# C# [Windows Forms] How to update Datagridview column, when button is pressed a second time

Tags: c#, datagridview, row

> I am a student learning C# I have been at this now since 11am GMT. I
> would appreciate help and will do the best I can to elaborate.

**1.** *I am tasked with creating a POS(like) system, this system is local and not connected to a database. I have decided I wanted to try using Datagridview to show "items", "Qty" and "Prices" by using a button for the item.*

> For context here is the Button and code **once pressed**:

[Button Example - Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekSob.png)

```
        private void sandwichBacon_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        *{
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            row.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
            row.Cells[0].Value = "Bacon";
            row.Cells[1].Value = 1 /*qty*/;
            row.Cells[2].Value = 3.5 /*price*/;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

**2.** *The button works fine, the required entries are added successfully. **However**, if I press the button again, **I do not want it to do this**:*

[Button Example - Duplicate Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZuk5.png)

**3.** What I require is the "Qty" section to auto update the amount once the button is pressed again. Every thing I can find on the web helps for those who wish to use ".Text" inputs. I stress again I am trying to do this by button click only.

I appreciate any help given and it would be beneficial to finally see it work going forward with my learning, I am sure I want to also use DataGriwView.

Thanks!

Comment: If your datagrid (dg) has no rows you add your item, if your dg already has rows you need to check and see if one of them matches the second item to be added, if there is a match you increase the quantity by adding the second quantity to the qty column in the dg. Another and better option, would be to add your items to a backing data object (e.g. a List) and then bind the list to your dg. Then when you need to change quantities or add items you only need to work with your list and then bind/update the dg, which would remove the need to traverse the dg rows and columns looking for your match.

Answer (score 0):

obviously you'll need to find if the item exist (Bacon) and if it exists Qty += 1, if not listed Qty =1

To search an item on your GridView:

```html
String searchValue = "Bacon";
int rowIndex = -1;
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
    {
        rowIndex = row.Index;
        break;
    }
}
```

**Using LINQ:**

```html
int rowIndex = -1;
DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => r.Cells["SystemId"].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
    .First();

rowIndex = row.Index;
```

If rowIndex <> -1 value exists Qty += 1 else Qty = 1